# Starting hostapd with script, interference from dhcpd

Tags: networking, raspbian, dhcp, hostapd

I'm trying to write a script that starts hostapd when called on raspbian, but I don't manage to get rid of the dhcp client process:

start-hostapd.sh

```
echo 'stopping wpa supplicant'
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service
sudo dhcpcd -k wlan0
echo 'bringing interface down'
ifdown wlan0
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.1
ifconfig wlan0 netmask 255.255.255.0
echo 'tarting hostapd'
systemctl start hostapd.service
ifup wlan0
systemctl start isc-dhcp-server.service
```

When I run it howerver the dhcp client gets active and blocks everything:

```
sudo sh start-hostapd.sh
stopping wpa supplicant
dhcpcd[1181]: sending commands to master dhcpcd process
bringing interface down
Killed old client process
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/b8:27:eb:b8:86:33
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/b8:27:eb:b8:86:33
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPRELEASE on wlan0 to 10.0.1.1 port 67
tarting hostapd
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/b8:27:eb:b8:86:33
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/b8:27:eb:b8:86:33
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPOFFER from 10.0.1.1
DHCPACK from 10.0.1.1
bound to 10.0.1.15 -- renewal in 33866 seconds.
```

How do I keep dhcpd from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is causing this, it's certainly not the dhcp **server** doing it, that just listens for requests and responds.  BTW, I've been running `hostapd` and `isc-dhcp-server` on my wlan0 for years - a dhcp server is pretty nearly essential for an AP.

It looks like you have a dhclient running on wlan0.  Maybe you have `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` in `/etc/network/interfaces`.  if so, change it to:

```
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

or maybe you're running network manager. nuke it from orbit.

Also, you should run `ifup wlan0` **before** starting `hostapd`.